# How to replace specific, unknown characters in Excel?

Tags: excel, replace

I'm using Excel 2013 and I'm trying to do a rather complex text transformation. It goes like this: let's say I have the follwing strings:

- `user_id`
- `profile_type_new`
- `user_refNumber`
- `campaign_period2`

What I'm trying to do is find a way to:

1. Get the character inmediately after the underscore and convert it to uppercase (_id becomes _Id, _period2 becomes _Period2).
2. After that, remove the underscore.

As reference, the strings should end like this:

- `userId`
- `profileTypeNew`
- `userRefNumber`
- `campaignPeriod2`

I've been wrecking my brains trying to find a function (or group of functions) that do this, without success. Can anyone poinbt me in the right direction or offer some examples of how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Léster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to write my own VBA function to achieve it. Thanks to everyone that pointed me in the right direction.

FYI, here's the function:

```
Public Function CamelCase(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim temp, loopresult As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim capitalize As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        temp = Mid(text, i, 1)
        If i = 1 Then
            loopresult = loopresult & LCase(temp)
        ElseIf temp = "_" Then
            capitalize = True
        ElseIf IsNumeric(temp) Then
            loopresult = loopresult & temp
            capitalize = True
        ElseIf capitalize = True Then
            loopresult = loopresult & UCase(temp)
            capitalize = False
        Else
            loopresult = loopresult & temp
        End If
    Next i
    CamelCase = loopresult
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_","")
```

First, convert it to proper case.  `Proper(A1)`
Then, remove all underscores.  `SUBSTITUTE(......,"_","")`

Comment: Works well but removes the uppercase letter already present. I need to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub XformData()
    Dim r As Range, U As String, N As Long
    U = "_"
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            s = r.Value
            N = InStr(1, s, U)
            If N <> 0 Then
                r.Value = Mid(s, 1, N - 1) & UCase(Mid(s, N + 1, 1)) & Mid(s, N + 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```